# jQuery jCarousel not working on iPhone

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

I'm using sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ for a vertical carousel to hold thumbnails of videos. On clicking, the src of the larger video changes.

I have two versions of the page- one with Flash navigation (http://www.smokingstinks-aaco.org/index-slide.html), and one with navigation using Javascript(http://www.smokingstinks-aaco.org/mobile). The one with the Flash navigation works fine, but the one using Javascript navigation is having some issues.

Everything works fine in Chrome, but on my iPhone 4S and the new iPad, when I scroll down to the last page, the last two thumbnails are missing, and then when I scroll back up all of the thumbnails are missing. I'm sure there is some difference that I am missing, but I can't find it. I even set up a demo page with nothing else on it, copied the code directly from Sorgalla's site and then added the elements I needed (you can find this page at www.smokingstinks-aaco.org/mobile/carousel-test.html).

This page is having the same issues. While I do know Javascript fairly well, I'm not too experienced with JQuery, so I'm hoping it's just some easy-to-fix issue I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when I added html{zoom: 2;} to my css, it messed up the way that jCarousel hides and shows the thumbnails. Works fine when removing that line.